# Matrix fields using Categories

Tags: matrix

Trying to template a matrix field that contains the use of categories. I am not a dev but trying to get this working.  This is my attempted but what I get back is something like this instead of the result.

> {{%content}}";s:12:"customFields";N;s:9:"inReverse";b:0;s:7:"asArray";b:0;s:2:"id";N;s:3:"uid";N;s:10:"fixedOrder";b:0;s:6:"status";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"enabled";}s:8:"archived";b:0;s:11:"dateCreated";N;s:11:"dateUpdate

Here is my code...

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('bizlist').limit(10) %}
  {% for entry in entries %}
{{ entry.title }}<br />
     {% for block in entry.cityList %}
{{ block.bizName }}
     {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `bizName` your categories field?  Try something like:

```
{% for category in block.bizName.all() %}
   {{ category.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I got this one covered by using .one() also.